# How can I separate jQuery autosuggest values?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

Hey guys, I'm using jQuery's autosuggest function and my question is, when the user selects multiple choices from the suggested values, how can I separate those values in php so I can insert them in a table or something?

Here's the form:

```
<table>
<form method="post" action="clippost.php" name="search">
<tr>
<td class="clip"><label><span><p class="signin">Clip Name:</p></span></label></td>
<td class="clip"><input type="text" name="clip" class="biginput" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="clip"><label><span><p class="signin">Topic:</p></span></label></td>
<td class="clip"><input type="text" name="topic" class="biginput" /></td>
<td class="clip"><p class="info">Seperate by commas.</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php 
$mysql=mysql_connect('localhost','***','***');
    mysql_select_db('jmtdy');
    $result=mysql_query("select * from users where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $dbarray=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $result2=mysql_query("select * from friendship where userid='".$dbarray['id']."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){

echo'
<td class="clip"><label><span><p class="signin">Clip-on people:</p></span></label></td>
<td class="clip"><input class="biginput" type="text" name="clippedon" id="suggestedfriend" /></td>
<td class="clip"><a class="neutral" href="faq.php#clipon"><p class="info">What is this?</p></a></td>
</tr>
';
}
else {
    echo'
    <td class="clip"><p class="signin">You need to have friends to clip-on people.</p></td>
    <td class="clip"><a class="neutral" href="faq.php#clipon"><p class="info">What is this?</p></a></td>
    ';
    }
    ?>
    <tr><td class="clip"><label><span><p class="signin">Editable:</p></span></label></td><td><select name="editable">

                                                            <option value="edit">Yes</option>
                                                            <option value="noedit">No</option>
                                                            </select></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input class="submitButton" type="submit" value="Create Clip" /> </td></tr>                                                     
</form>
</table>
```

And the jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    var data = {items: [
    <?php 

    $mysql=mysql_connect('localhost','***','***');
    mysql_select_db('jmtdy');
    $result=mysql_query("select * from users where username='".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
    $dbarray=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $result2=mysql_query("select * from friendship where userid='".$dbarray['id']."'");
    while($dbarray2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $result3=mysql_query("select * from users where id='".$dbarray2['friendid']."'");
        $dbarray3=mysql_fetch_assoc($result3);


        echo '{value: "'.$dbarray3['id'].'", name: "'.$dbarray3['username'].'"},';
        }
        ?>
]};
$("#suggestedfriend").autoSuggest(data.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});
});







</script>
```

And clippost.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="Cliproid" class=" no_js">
<head>
    <link href='graphics/icon.png' rel='icon' type='image/png'/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Mainstyles.css" TYPE="text/css"></link>
    <Title>Cliproid</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php 
$mysql=mysql_connect('localhost','*********','********');
    mysql_select_db('jmtdy');
$clip=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clip']); 
$topic=mysql_real_real_escape_string($_POST['topic']);

$editable=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['editable']);
print_r($_POST['clippedon']);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what post (or possibly get) data your server is receiving from the form. Use printr($_POST); to see the data, and if you are not able to extract it, post the output of printr here.

--

I've tested your code, the problem was that your form was inside of your table. That is, I believe, not allowed in html, but nevertheless works in major browser. However when the autoSuggest plugin appends a hidden input to the table, the form will not pick this up.

The solution: write `<form><table>..</table></form>` instead of `<table><form>..</form></table>`

This will get your data to the clippost.php script. However, as you will see, the data will be stored in a random field name every run (as_values_xx where x is a number). To use a stable field name you should invoke `autoSuggest` with the `asHtmlID` parameter.

In `clippost.php` can use `$yourarray = explode(',',$_POST['as_values_your_custom_id']);` to get the entries out of the field. It is comma separated and `explode` splits at comma's to form an array.

Comment: @JoukeWaleson I get nothing when I print_r the $_POST or when I echo it, even though I selected values. Any help?

Comment: Oops, I meant print_r of course, not printr, good thing you caught on that. You can try to see if the data is in $_GET in the same manner. If there is nothing, please post the html and javascript of your form in your question.

Comment: @JoukeWaleson Nope, still nothing even with $_GET. I will post the code in my question.

Comment: This looks alright, but some pointers:
1) your un/pw is visible in the last snippet
2) correct indention would make it a bit easier to read
3) imho mixing javascript and php is not too neat. You should let jQuery use a php file as a resource. Also try using json_encode in php.

Comment: I've just tested and added the solution to my post.